# QuickFIX/J - how to stop Initiator automatic logon

Tags: quickfixj

We have implemented initiator , web bases where user login by entering the session ID details like beginstring, compid,targetcompid.
Now, we are facing scenario where,  first time, due to some reason,it got disconnecting message.
But after some time, it will automatically logon. And appear suddenly as connected in users table.
So how can we stop that ?
We want that, once he got disconnected message ,for him it should be disconnected only until he enters the details again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent automatic logon of Initiator you could use one of these ways:

1. Call `logout()` on the session. This will set the session to disabled which will prevent reconnection. If it is OK to relogin, call `logon()`.
2. Implement `ApplicationExtended.canLogon()` and return `false`. If it is OK to relogin, return `true`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly  , session got created ans established only once. SO further we are doing logon and logout whenever the user enters details.  Say,  user  1 logged on with the session 1  . Now user 2 try to logon the same session by calling logon, in that case , it should get disconnected ,and in that disconnect, calling logout.  In such case, will the user1 also get logged out?

Comment: I don't know how you have implemented the user concept in your application so I can't really comment on that. But what I can say is: if you call logon() multiple times it will not log out a session.

Comment: My initiator config has resetOnLogon=Y, refreshOnLogon=Y.  Now  in above scenario,we called logout in disconnect.  Next time instead of logon,we are calling initiator.start () . So programmatically not calling logon.  This scenario working very well when we establish the session using our Web version tool.

Comment: ??? Starting the initiator twice will not have any effect if you don't stop it first. https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/beb7b03f7a084789364c34a80f489ae87f4f6da2/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/SocketInitiator.java#L123

Comment: A FIX session is a point-to-point connection between TWO parties. If you share it you will run into problems. I suggest you make yourself a little more acquainted with the protocol, e.g. on https://www.fixtrading.org/standards/fix-session-layer-online/ . Maybe re-think your application design. In the future please invest more time into creating your questions. It started with "stopping auto logon" now it is about multiple users logging into a FIX session... *sigh* If you create better questions there maybe will be more users being able to help you out. At the moment it's very hard to do so.